# How to loop through xml data that is stored in XML format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a SQL query that currently gets the value that is stored in a column in my database like this:

```
SELECT 
    @filevalue = (CAST(REPLACE(CAST(de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"', '') AS XML).value('(//value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)')), 
    @filecontent = de.ENVIRONMENT_ID
FROM
    dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT AS de
WHERE
    de.ENVIRONMENT_ID = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@filevalue AS numeric(19, 0)), 'encoding="uft-16"', '') AS numeric(19, 0))
```

The part where it is `.value('(//value)[1]')` is the problem because sometimes there will be multiple value nodes.  I tried to concatenate a counter and the value node together but this came back with the error the value needs to be a string not a varchar when I did this: `.value(@ValueNodes, 'NVARCHAR(max)'))`

So how can I successfully loop through the xml to get my result? The problem with the way I was doing it is that the first value is not always what I need and will give errors (null values and unable to cast types).

Comment: Do you need to store ALL values? Or just loop until you find the desired one?

Comment: not necessary but the desired one could be any value plus the max nodes I think would be 5 (most I seen was 3) so if it would store them all it would probably be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **deep search `XPath`**, which will find **all `<value>`-nodes wherever they are**. You do this with a double `//` at the beginning. The following will extract all `text()` within each `<value>` together with the parent node name:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
  <value>test1</value>
  <SomeParent>
    <value>test in parent</value>
    <value>one more in parent</value>
  </SomeParent>
  <value>One more on first level</value>
</root>';

SELECT val.value(N'(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TheValueInValue
      ,val.value(N'local-name(..)','nvarchar(max)') AS ParentNode
FROM @xml.nodes(N'//value') AS Each(val)
```

The result

```
TheValueInValue           ParentNode
test1                     root
test in parent            SomeParent
one more in parent        SomeParent
One more on first level   root
```

### UPDATE

> ...as I am getting the xml from a column

This is a blind flight, but you might need something like this:

```
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT 
         TheXML = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"', '') AS XML)
        ,de.ENVIRONMENT_ID
    FROM
        dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT AS de
)
SELECT Casted.ENVIRONMENT_ID
      ,val.value(N'(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TheValueInValue
      ,val.value(N'local-name(..)','nvarchar(max)') AS ParentNode
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY TheXML.nodes(N'//value') AS Each(val)
```

Comment: cool can I do this basically @xml = de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA (I know that's now to make that value equal that but just for quickness) for that part as I am getting the xml from a column